# Merging two different data frames in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have two data frames. 
The one consists of three variables, namely "date", "strike" and "vol" with 20 observations a day, 100 a month and 1200 a year (in trading days), which looks like this

```
Date         Price       Vol
2008-09-01   20          0.2
2008-09-01   30          0.5
...
```

So for each month I have certain values for price and vol, ranging from 10 to 40, 0.1 to 0.7, respectively.
The second one includes interpolated values from the first one. So I do not have the date anymore, however small steps for the other variables:

```
  Price       Vol
   20          0.2
   21          0.21
   22          0.24
   30          0.5
```

So, while one frame shows values in a discrete time, the other one is more or less of continuous nature.
Now my question: how is it possible to tell R to merge the second data frame into the first one, taking over the dates for the continuous prices/vols between the two discrete ones, to get to something like this:

```
Date         Price       Vol
2008-09-01   20          0.2
2008-09-01   21          0.21
2008-09-01   22          0.24
...
2008-09-01   30          0.5
```

I just cannot figure out how to do it. I always ended up with NA values for the dates which are no longer in ascending order.

Thank you very much for your support
Dani

Comment: please add the code that gives the non-desired result and give us the structure of your data. is Date of class POSIXlt, Data, chron, character,... ? for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I totally missed the point with the first post. This one does the date. But I agree with Shane that unless some downstream function requires data frames, then a time series is a good idea.

```
A <- data.frame(date=rep("2001-05-25", 2), price=c(20, 30), vol=c(0.2, 0.5))
B <- data.frame(price=seq(min(A$price), max(A$price), by=1))
C <- merge(A, B, all=TRUE)
index <- which(!is.na(C$vol))
for (i in seq(nrow(A))[-1]) {
    C$date[index[i-1]:index[i]] <- rep(A$date[i-1], A$price[i] - A$price[i-1] + 1)
    C$vol[index[i-1]:index[i]] <- seq(A$vol[i-1], A$vol[i], length=(A$price[i] - A$price[i-1] + 1))
}
ans <- C[, c(2, 1, 3)]

 ans 
         date price  vol
1  2001-05-25    20 0.20
2  2001-05-25    21 0.23
3  2001-05-25    22 0.26
4  2001-05-25    23 0.29
5  2001-05-25    24 0.32
6  2001-05-25    25 0.35
7  2001-05-25    26 0.38
8  2001-05-25    27 0.41
9  2001-05-25    28 0.44
10 2001-05-25    29 0.47
11 2001-05-25    30 0.50
```

Answer (score 4):

First, use a time series class (e.g. `zoo` or `xts`).

Your second interpolated time series should still have a timestamp, even if it is hourly or every minute, etc.  Use `merge` to bring them together, then use `na.locf` to carry the values forward from the lower frequency time series.

Here's an example:

```
ts1 <- zoo(1:5, as.POSIXct(as.Date("2010-10-01") + 1:5))
ts2 <- zoo(1:(5 * 24), as.POSIXct("2010-10-01 00:00:00") + (1:(5 * 24) * 3600))
na.locf(merge(ts1, ts2))
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is the correct solution to the wrong question. You don't even need time series. See Date as a factor of which the levels have to spread over the second dataframe, starting from the values of the first data frame. Too lazy to look for the solution, but it has been solved here already.

Comment: @Joris I may be missing something, but I think that my example does what he wants.  And yes, a time series is not necessary, but it's useful.

Comment: Your starting point is not correct. ts1 should look like  zoo(seq(1,by=24,length.out=5), as.POSIXct(as.Date("2010-10-01") + 1:5)). And then you should get a dataframe where you have the dates in ts1 repeated 24 times, but with the values of ts2. At least that's what I made of it.