# averaging/combining duplicated values in a data frame

Tags: r

```
sampleName     realConc      exptname concentrate timepoints replicate    day  var
  name1    3.877049e-05           0hr        55mM          0        b1 011311   1
  name1    3.293085e-04           0hr        55mM          0        b1 011311   2
  name2    2.939995e-03 KClpulse-5min        55mM         20        b1 011411   1
  name2    1.212584e-02 KClpulse-5min        55mM         20        b1 011411   2
```

here's an example data frame named 'ex'

I want to average the realConc values for the rows which are have duplicated values in columns: exptname,concentrate,timepoints,replicate,and day.

Then make one row with this new average, and the same sampleName

I've been thinking 
  mean(ex[which(duplicated(paste(ex$exptname,ex$concentrate,ex$timepoints,ex$replicate,ex$day))),]$realConc)

#### the problem with this is that it will average every single value that is duplicated in these columns, even if they are different from each other

#### i need this to happen for every unique value within each column

then I need one row with an averaged realConc value and the same sampleName as whichever rows were averaged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that if I understand you correctly, you should just be able to use `aggregate()`.

Assuming your `data.frame` is named `ex`:

```
aggregate(realConc ~ ., mean, data = ex)
  sampleName      exptname concentrate timepoints replicate   day     realConc
1      name1           0hr        55mM          0        b1 11311 0.0001840395
2      name2 KClpulse-5min        55mM         20        b1 11411 0.0075329175
```

Comment: let's say you have one column though that is not the same, can you stil aggregate?

Comment: @LucasPinto, Do you mean to aggregate based on everything except for the new column you added?

Comment: yes, in reality there is about twenty more columns that could be unequal, i just want to aggregate according to these five or so, but yes

Comment: Ya, I could do that, but if I were to later want to add those, I guess that isn't a posibility

Comment: @LucasPinto, If you only want to aggregate a particular set of columns, drop the columns you don't want to use for "aggregate by". In the aggregation formula, we're saying "aggregate `realConc` by everything else in the dataset". Which may not be what you want to do. You should be clear about what you want to aggregate by, and then you can use merge. See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11991912/1270695).